# what is this circle please?

Tags: rhythm, sight-reading, tablature

I'm a bit confused about what these ovals mean (which I've tried to circle in white)? Thanks for any help! Does anyone know of a good comprehensive online guide about reading tab rhythms and shorthand too? It would really help me!

Thanks so much for any help you can provide.All the best,
Osla

Comment: I think you forgot to put the picture.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the notation, with enough surrounding material to understand the context. Please also provide information about where the notation comes from (e.g. author and title), and for what instrument it is.

Comment: Do you mean the fret number 0? See [here](https://www.pickupmusic.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-reading-guitar-tab).